# Why acceleration bigger when upward force is present?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Imagine object is falling down and has a mass of 1kg. There's an upward force on it of 50N. Let's calculate what the acceleration is.

$$ F_n = ma = 50 - mg = 50 - 9.8 = 40.2 $$

where `a` becomes 40.2.

How is it possible that when object is in free fall (no upward force acting on it), acceleration is much less 9.8 than when there's upward force ? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The upward force in your example is much larger than gravity, so your object will accelerate upward with a large acceleration. Why does this not make sense?

Comment: Because you are accelerating it with upward force. And the force due to gravity depends upon the mass and you are taking small consider same situation and a 50kg mass

Answer (score 6):

Because it is about direction, as well as magnitude.

Force is a vector and adds like vectors, meaning directions are necessary. If we include directions, and take down toward earth as the *negative* direction:

- An object of mass $1\ kg$ has a gravitational force of about $F_g=mg=-9.8\ N$ with (free-fall) acceleration of $-9.8\ ms^{-2}$.
- If we include the applied force on the same mass of $+50\ N$, the net force is $F_u=+50-mg=+40.2\ N$ and the object is not accelerating to the ground, but *upwards* since $F_u\gt F_g$  (with an acceleration of $+40.2\ ms^{-2}$).